# How to access drf api from react after userd logged in in django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have mostly been using Django templates for my front end and everything works fine. I want to learn about DRF and React and I want to be able to have both communicate to each other. I have react running on port 3000 and django on 8000 so there is a miscommunication and I can't test my code as I get the error 403 (forbidden). I have the following view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def user_details_api(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    current_user = request.user
    id = current_user.id
    status = 200
    try:
        obj = CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)
        data = userSerializer(obj)
        return Response(data.data, status=status)
    except:
        status = 404
        return Response(status=404)
```

I have the following react end point:

```
 function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      } 
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
console.log("This is the token: "+csrftoken)
function loadUserInfo(callback){
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let method = 'GET';
  let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userdetails/6";
  xhr.responseType = "json"; // Let the xhr request know that its getting a json 
  xhr.open(method, url); //This opens the request with the method and url entered
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
  if (csrftoken){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
  }
  xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status==403){
      let detail = xhr.response.detail;
      if(detail ==="Authentication credentials were not provided.");
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("login")===-1){
          window.location.href="/login"
        }
    }
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function(){
    callback({"message":"The request was an error"}, 400)
  }
  xhr.send();//Trigger that request
}
```

I see in the details that the credentials were not provided and I am wondering how to fix this as the tutorial I watched did not seem to provide any aside from logging in on the django side using the stock login form which I also did. I also noticed that the csrftoken is null. I also included CORS settings and trusted origins as well as drf settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://127.0.0.1','.cfe.sh','http://localhost','http://localhost:3000']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000','http://localhost:8000']
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

I am not sure how to do proceed, most solutions online deal with tokens and I am not sure that is the only solution specially since I am not entirely using react for the front end and the login page is rendered by Django. Any idea how to proceed in my use case would be appreciated as I only need to run some specific pages with react that will serve more as practice for me than anything else where I will delete and update the data. I am just starting to learn about this concept but cannot test code when my endpoints are not communicating.

Comment: Every time when u make a request from the react site, the Django backend has to verify who is making the request so there would be the implementation of an access token that can be stored in localStorage on the client (react) site. So every time you have to pass that access token otherwise Django wont be able to verify your request

Comment: So if I am not mistaken I can use a csrf token. As the documentation specifies I need the function getCookie(name) function to retrieve it but I put this on the react side and it returns null. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I would highly recommend consulting this repo https://github.com/rrebase/knboard/ how the auth part was handled with CSRF token. this will help you a lot.